# You and your child are standing in front of the lift waiting for it to open. At that moment it opens, would you say "here we go"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

> [here we go](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/here_1#here_idmg_6)
>
> ​(informal) said when something is starting to happen
>
> ‘Here we go,’ thought Fred, ‘she's sure to say something.’

You and your child are standing in front of the lift waiting for it to open so that you can go down.

At that moment the lift opens, would you say "**here we go**"?

Comment: I fear this is an opinion-based question. Personally I would be inclined to say 'in we go', but 'here we go' certainly wouldn't be wrong.

Comment: @JMB I disagree, it's gotta be "In we go!". Otherwise, what will we say when the elevator starts to move?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty 'down we go'?

Comment: @JMB Hmmm. Yes, good point! Or 'up we go'! When it stops, "Off we go!", then "Away we go!"

Comment: Exactly! I definitely prefer 'in we go' over 'here we go' in this case, but wanted OP to know it wouldn't be horribly wrong.

Comment: @JMB, why is it opinion-based?. This is absolutely a valuable question. I have never heard "In / down / away / off we go" in my life. That is so strange. That is why learners need to know more about it. Maybe you are biased against the question. Respect non-native learners.

Comment: Tom, you asked "_Would_ you say 'Here we go'?" Well, most of us probably wouldn't; we might say 'Here's the lift', 'In we go', 'Come along' etc. etc., but  there's nothing wrong with saying 'Here we go'.

Comment: @Tom, I certainly mean no disrespect! I am a teacher of English and learner of multiple languages myself, so I would ask you kindly not to question my respect. I also answered your question in my first comment; I didn't shut you down! The reason I think the question is somewhat opinion-based is due to the fact I wouldn't say 'here we go' (though it's not wrong), which leads to opinions on what I (and others) *would* say.

Comment: @JMB. My apology, I thought you said bad things about me. Ignore the above message